# ¿Porque JSON.stringify() me devuelve un arreglo vacio?

Tags: javascript, json

```
/* Validar checkboxes clickeados */
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.single-checkbox');
var clickeados = new Array();

checkboxes.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if(elem.checked) {
           if(!clickeados.includes(elem)){
                   clickeados.push(elem);
//                   console.log(clickeados);
           }
        }
        else{
            if(clickeados.includes(elem)){
                   clickeados.pop(elem);
//                   console.log(clickeados);
            }
        }
    });
});

/* Validar cuantos gustos fueron seleccionados antes de hacer el submit */
$('#vasitoForm').on('submit', (event) => {
    if(clickeados.length == 0){
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("errorGustos").innerHTML = "Debe seleccionar por lo menos un gusto";
    }
    else if(clickeados.length > 0 && clickeados.length < 3){
    console.log(clickeados);
        var myArray = JSON.stringify(clickeados);
//        $('#vasitoForm').attr('action', myArray + '/pedido');
        console.log(myArray);
    }
});
```

El console.log(clickeados) me imprime el arreglo de input's perfectamente, pero cuando lo quiero convertir a JSON y lo vuelvo a imprimir el JSON me sale vacio ...

> Array [ input.single-checkbox ] home.js:59:5
>
> [{}] home.js:62:9

Comment: No es un array vacío: `[{}]`es un array con ún único elemento que es un objeto vacío

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando `JSON.stringify` itera tu array para convertirlo a string, se encuentra con el elemento `input.single-checkbox` que es un nodo HTML y no sabe como convertirlo a string, por eso queda como un objeto vacío.

```
JSON.stringify([elem])
// "[{}]"
```

Te recomiendo que mejor armes tu propio objeto sólo con las propiedades que uses del nodo HTML y eso sea lo que conviertas a través de `JSON.stringify`

```
JSON.stringify([{props:1}])
// "[{"props":1}]"
```

Comment: Bien explicado, iba a poner lo mismo que tú pero te adelantaste

Comment: Gracias a todos :)